# Angular - routing trouble

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, httpclient, angular-components

it's my first post here. I'm having some trouble with my code. I want my system to redict me to another page when I delete a client but it only redirects me to the home page. The function deletes a client perfectly. Here's a part of my code.

SERVICE:

```
deleteClientHttp(id: number){

this.router.navigate(['test']); /* I want to redirects me here */
return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/${id}`);
}
```

COMPONENT (list clients) WHICH CONSUMES THE SERVICE:

```
onDeleteClient(id: number) {

const ok = confirm(`Do you want to delete the client with id: ${id}`)
if (ok) {
  this.clientService.deleteClientHttp(id)
    .subscribe(
      {
        next: () => {
          alert(`Client removed sucessfully`);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          alert(`Error!!`);
        }
      }
    );
}
```

}

ROUTES:

```
const routes: Routes = [

{path:'home',component:ListClientsComponent},
{path:'new', component: NewClientComponent},
{path:'edit/:id', component: EditClientComponent},
{path:'test', component: TestComponent},
{path:'**', component: ListClientsComponent},
];
```

I tried changing 'test' for '/test' but nothing changed. But what I realized is that 'next' attribute on subscribe never executes...

Comment: change this: `this.router.navigate(['test']);` to this `this.router.navigate(['/test']);`. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Looks like a race condition. Compose the navigation promise with the delete http observable like `return concat(this.http.delete(url), this.router.navigate(['/test']));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the route with the forward slash. In your case :

```
this.router.navigate(['/test']);
```

Answer (score 0):

move `this.router.navigate(['test']);` form service file to component file, and put that line on the success response, to be like that:

```
onDeleteClient(id: number) {

const ok = confirm(`Do you want to delete the client with id: ${id}`)
if (ok) {
  this.clientService.deleteClientHttp(id)
    .subscribe(
      {
        next: () => {
          this.router.navigate(['test']); // will redirect once the service done
          alert(`Client removed sucessfully`);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          alert(`Error!!`);
        }
      }
    );
}
```